# pytest не реагирует в bash

Tags: python, pytest, git-bash, windows-11

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в **PowerShell** и **cmd** `pytest`
получается вызвать напрямую, а в **bash** приходится использовать `python -m pytest`, иначе ничего не происходит и **bash** ждёт следующей команды.

Comment: Потому что путь к папке с исполняемым файлом pytest никто не прописывал в башевую переменную окружения PATH, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal, а можно подробнее? Где нужно прописать? А при создании venv, если я pytest туда ставлю, каждый раз новый путь добавлять? Или направьте где об этом почитать, если долго объяснять. Спасибо